# BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a number: [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: solidity, tokens, javascript

Getting this Big Number error when trying to update my token price.Seems like a Javascript issue with the number size being passed.Anyone know a fix for this?

```
//Javascript
priceChange:function(){
App.contracts.DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  let newPrice = document.getElementById('updatePrice');
  newPrice = web3.toWei(newPrice, 'ether');
  instance.setTokenPrice(newPrice);
})
```

}

```
 // Solidity 
function setTokenPrice(uint256 _newPrice) public{
  tokenPrice = _newPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually just a plain old Javascript problem.

This line:

`let newPrice = document.getElementById('updatePrice');` 
is referring to the `updatePrice` DOM element, not the contents of that element.

But this  function:

`web3.toWei`, takes a number as its first argument. You're passing a DOM element.

You need to change the former so that `newPrice` is a number and not an element. If you're unsure how to do this, you're best off asking in regular old Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah I feel stupid, sorry I was overlooking the problem and thought it was something else. Just forgot to add .value to the end. Thanks for that.